# change option selected based on datatables data

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a datatable which display my user's data from my database.

```
|    id    |    name    |    region    |    chapter    |
     1         Jane            1               3
     2         John            1               5
     3         Joy             2               7
     4         Jack            3               5
     5         Jade            4               4
```

each region have of 10 chapter

```
$('select[name="region"]').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val()
    $.get('/api/chapters', function(data) {

      $('select[name="chapter"]').empty().append(
        data.filter(function (o) {

          return o.region == val
        }).map(function (o) {

          return '<option value="' + o.id + '">' + o.chapterName + '</option>'
        }).join('')
      )
    })
  })
```

i used this script to get the list of all chapters then `map` them based on the region of the user so when i clicked the button to edit the user's info this script should run and select the chapter based on the data from datatable.

```
dt.on('click', 'button.btn-link', function () {
    tr = $(this).closest('tr')
    data = dt.row(tr).data()
    form  = $('#form-update')

    Object.keys(data).map(function (key) {
      var el = form.find('[name="' + key + '"]')
      if (el.is('select')) {
        el.val(data[key]).trigger('change')
      }

    })

    $('.modal').modal({ backdrop: 'static' })
  })
```

but what happen is when i clicked the button to edit, the selected chapter was the first option from the select element not the data that was saved from my database.

so if i tried to edit `userId 1` the select element for region and chapter looked like this

```
region  |   chapter
  1            1 (Selected)
  ...          ...
```

but the form should look liked this

```
region  |   chapter
  1            3 (Selected)
  ...          1
               2
               ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the chapter from database, make an `id` for each option and make an `if condition` then using jquery's [.prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) to change the option's `selected` attribute.

Here's an example:

```
if (CHAPTER_FROM_DB == "1") {
   $("#CHAPTER1_ID").prop("selected", true);
}
else if (condition) {
   // some code here...
}
else {
   // some code here...
}
```